# How can I put an image from DB table in Web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to put an image in view section I have defined a table but it seems`{{for table in tables:}}` doesn't work. My code is:

**default.py** (Controller)

```
def index():
    return dict(message=T('Hello World'))

def Tables(): 
   return dict(tables=db().select(db.table.ALL))

def download():
    return response.download(request, db)
```

**db.py** (model)

```
db.define_table('table',
          Field('image', type='upload')
```

This is it and I tried to do `{{for table in tables:}}` before putting the image, but it says, the `tables is not defined.`I used `{{pass}}` after `for`. Can you guys help me a bit?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to edit which view?

from your code it will work well:

in model

```
db.define_table('mytable',
          Field('image', type='upload'))

# I do not recommend calling a table 'table' it is can be a reserved keyword
```

in dontrollers/default.py

```
def tables(): 
   return dict(tables=db().select(db.mytable.ALL))
```

in views/default/tables.html

```
{{for table in tables:}}
    <img src="{{=URL('default', 'download', args=table.image)}}" /> <br />
{{pass}}
```