# web2py: image not displaying

Tags: python, image, web2py

I am simply trying to display all the images that I have stored in my db table:

```
db.define_table('tbl_profile',
            Field('id', 'integer'),
            Field('name', 'string'),
            Field('company', 'string'),
            Field('title', 'string'),   
            Field('image', type='upload'),
```

In menu.py I have:

```
response.menu = [  
             (T('Show'),False,URL('app/default','show')),
             (T('Contact'),False, URL('app/default', 'contact')),
             (T('Test'),False, URL('app/default', 'test'))  
]
```

I have tried the following, in default.py:

```
def show(): 
    return dict(show=db().select(db.tbl_proile.image))
```

and in show.html:

```
{{for tbl_profile in show:}}
<img src="{{=URL('default', 'download', args=tbl_card.image)}}" /> <br />
{{pass}}
```

My download function is the default one provided by web2py. When I click on the "show" tab it brings me to a page but it shows a broken image.

I looked at the db and the upload folder and it looks like the image was loaded properly.

Thanks for any help. I have been stuck on this for quite a bit.

Comment: That looks correct. Did you make any changes to the model definition after uploading the files? Can you show the exact path and filename for one or two files that have been uploaded but aren't showing up?

Comment: I don't think I changed the model definition. However, I did move the actual file into a folder I named "images" into the app itself. I noticed this did remove the file from the db but I re-uploaded the file in appadmin and I still have this error.

The file name: cm1.jpeg
The file path: user/workspace/prof/prof/applications/app/images

Comment: When I extend layout.html I don't see anything, but when I remove that I see the broken image icon. When I right click and view image I get redirected to this page: download/tbl_profile.image.b610ad43eefff374.436c61796d6f72654d616964312e6a706567.jp‌​eg Which says "invalid request."

Comment: First, moving or removing files won't remove anything from the db. Second, cm1.jpeg is not the name that the web2py upload mechanism would have given to the file.

Comment: I referred to the other post you wrote regarding uploading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702625/how-can-i-put-an-image-from-db-table-in-web2py

This worked at one point. Then after deleting files from uploads/modifying the db seemed to mess something up. I reverted back to the same setup you wrote in that post and I still see two broken images. (I only have one image in the db) is it doing some weird cache perhaps?

Comment: I didn't write that answer, though it looks like it should work. Have you started from scratch by clearing the db and doing completely new uploads? It's hard to say what you might have broken by modifying things earlier.

Comment: Oh I think there was another answer you wrote that helped me. I am starting from scratch now and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of the built-in upload and download functionality, then you have to upload the files using a `SQLFORM` (which includes appadmin, `Crud`, and `SQLFORM.grid`) and download the files using `response.download()` (there are also some more advanced options for special cases). Once you have uploaded a file, you cannot then move or rename it if you want to take advantage of the automatic download feature.